# understanding of switchmap in rxjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, angularjs, react-native, rxjs

I am new to rxjs. I am trying to understand switchmap functionality. I have written the following code for understanding.

```
const fun1 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve("Fun1"));
  };
  const fun2 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve("Fun2"));
  };
  const fun3 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve("Fun3"));
  };

  const observer = from(fun()).pipe(
    switchMap((result1) => {
      return from(fun1());
    }),
    switchMap((result2) => { 
      return from(fun2())
    }),
    switchMap((result3) => {
      return from(fun3());
    })
  );
  observer.subscribe(
    (val) => console.log("Val =", val),
    (error) => console.log("Error = ", error),
    () => console.log("Completed")
  );
```

Above code returns Fun3 to subscriber.

But my expectation is if fun2() returns promise with "Fun2" string then code should not execute the switchmap with from(fun3()); And code should return "Fun2 to the subscriber. How can I achieve this functionality in the above mentioned code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've re-written your code so it might be a bit easier to see why you're always getting "fun3".

```ts
const fun1 = () => of("Fun1");
const fun2 = () => of("Fun2");
const fun3 = () => of("Fun3");

const observable = from(fun()).pipe(
  switchMap(_ => fun1()),
  switchMap(_ => fun2()),
  switchMap(_ => fun3()),
);

observer.subscribe({
  next: val => console.log("Val =", val),
  error: err => console.log("Error = ", err),
  complete: () => console.log("Completed")
});
```

First, notice how my switchMaps all ignore their input? That should give you a hint that the "return value" from the previous observable is ignored.

`switchMap(_ => fun1())` is saying "Whenever the source observable emits a value (I don't care what the value is), then subscribe to the observable returned by `fun1`."

Here's another example:

```ts
const observable = from(fun()).pipe(
  switchMap(result => result == "Fun2"? of(result) : fun1()),
  switchMap(result => result == "Fun2"? of(result) : fun2()),
  switchMap(result => result == "Fun2"? of(result) : fun3()),
);
```

Now you have observables that are checking the intermediate results.

- The first result is whatever `fun()` emits, if that's not `"Fun2"`, then `fun1()` is called.
- The second result is `"Fun1"` and since that isn't `"Fun2"` either, then `fun2()` is called
- The third result is `"Fun2"`! AHA! Now we return an observable that emits `"Fun2"` instead of calling `fun3()`

Answer (score 1):

switchMap, like exhaustMap or mergeMap, is used to flatten observables of observables. The special thing about switchMap is, that if your source observable (in your case: from(fun())), emits a new value, the switchMap operator will unsubscribe from the previous inner observable before subscribing to the new one.
Therefore you will always only have one inner subscription.
This ng-conf talk explains it perfectly:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUZ9CjcaCEw

In your example you use the pipe function to pipe three switchMaps. The value of your observable (in your subscribe method) will always be the last transformation you made in the pipe function (in your case ("Fun3")).

For your specific example you could do something like:

```
const observer = from(fun).pipe(
    switchMap((result2) => { 
      return from(fun2()).pipe(
        catchError(error => fun3())
      )
    })
  );
```

This way fun3() only gets called if fun2() rejects otherwise your subscriber will receive the result of fun2().

But I would highly recommend you to watch the talk its only 20 minutes and really explains what switchMap does.